# npm install -SE with minor versions notation

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, npm, npm-install

Don't know whether this is a missing feature or I'm doing something wrong but I have the following "problem".

Lets say I want to install the foo@3.2.x package and save it automatically in my package.json

```
npm install foo@3.2.x -S
```

This would write in my package.json the version ^3.2.0

```
npm install foo@3.2.x -SE
```

This would write in my package.json the version 3.2.0

What if I want to profit of the patch versions notation and I want to have the 3.2.x in my package.json?
The only option is adding it manually?

Thanks!

Comment: If I'm understanding your question correctly, you don't need to do the `.x` version.  If you install and `--save` it appends the `^` prefix to the version.  This allows any version to install as long as the Major and Minor version numbers match.  Any patch version equal to or newer than the one you installed will be installed.  So for example `^3.2.0` will allow 3.2.0 and 3.2.1 and so on.  `^3.2.2` will allow 3.2.2, 3.3.3 and so on, but not 3.2.1 or 3.2.0.  Is that what you are looking to accomplish?

Comment: You are right, my question was wrong written. My idea is to have a package.json with the format 3.2.x so I can fetch all the patches on npm update, not the minor or major versions. Seems that the only way to do that is by editing the package.json file...

Comment: That's what the ^ symbol does, it will only update the package if a patch version comes out.  It will not update the package if a new minor or major version comes out.

Comment: No, actually the ^ symbol updates the minor versions and also patches. After  @saintedlama answer I found out that ~ symbol updates only patches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The semver shorthand `~` can be used to install only patch version updates of packages but not minor or major version updates (See https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver#tilde-ranges-123-12-1). To make this the default in npm use `npm config` command

`npm config set save-prefix=~`

Now the tilde will be used for every package installed with

`npm install foo -S`

And only patch level updates are installed when using `npm i`.

Comment: Great! I used the .npmrc so is for all developers the same.